# How do i add a web api to an existing asp.net mvc core 6 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to add a web API endpoint to an existing web application. How do I go about doing this?
Here is the GitHub link https://github.com/GrindingLife/BHFunctioning

I have tried adding a scaffold of an API controller in the controller folder. When launched accessing the localhost/api does not work. I do not know what to add to the Program.cs file. All the examples that I've seen are for startup.cs file instead of program.cs

Here is my program.cs file

```
using BHFunctioning.Controllers;
using BHFunctioning.Data;
using BHFunctioning.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
         policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
});
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
            new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it, i just needed to add the following into Program.cs and call it using localhost:2444/api/{controller name}

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```